# Convert js to jq to resize one object compared to the other next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, resizable

I have a problem that I am dealing with, need a resizable window dragged by the side.

Unfortunately resizable() in jq doesn't work for me and resize in css doesn't give me the proper solution I need. I was searching the web and found a solution that might work for me, unfortunately it is in js and I need it in jq

```
var resize = document.querySelector("#resize");
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var moveX =
   left.getBoundingClientRect().width +
   resize.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;

var resize = document.querySelector("#resize");
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var moveX =
   left.getBoundingClientRect().width +
   resize.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;


var drag = false;
resize.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
   drag = true;
   moveX = e.x;
  console.log(moveX);
});

container.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
   moveX = e.x;
   if (drag)
      left.style.width =
         moveX - resize.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 + "px";
});


container.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
   drag = false;
});
```

Here it is also on codepen, so you have idea how it should work `[codepen]`(https://codepen.io/LukAnd/pen/ZEMgLoq?editors=0010)

The function getBoundingClientRect is not in jq and what I tried to exchange it with was width() then x with offset().left but I cannot recreate it fully.
If someone would be so nice and help me, I appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You can get any DOM element from JQ element by doing $(el)[0] as in `$(el)[0].getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Also `$el.offset().left, $el.offset().top,  $el.width(), $el.height()`